# Solving route in multimodal network dataset does not use all forms of transport available?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, network-analyst, routing, multimodal-network

After having completed [Exercise 2](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Exercise_2_Creating_a_multimodal_network_dataset/00470000005v000000/) in the official Esri [Network Analyst Tutorial](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00470000005r000000), I decided to find a route in the multimodal dataset, to see how it functions. After adding several network locations along an intentionally long route, I pressed Solve. I was quite surprised to find that the route chosen took walking along the streets as the only transportation mode available (despite railway stations and lines being included in the dataset).

I placed my origin and destination points quite far apart close to metro entrances, so I assumed that the directions would include walking to that first metro entrance, travelling on the train to the last metro entrance, exiting the station and walking to the destination point. The route ArcMap gave me indicated I would have to walk 3 hrs 46 mins along the streets to get to my destination!

[image: Route]

I looked at the `Analysis Settings`, but I am not familiar enough with Network Analyst to know if something needs to be changed in order to get the results I want.

How do I ensure that the route chosen uses all available forms of transport to find the shortest route?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting that result because you chose **PedestrianTime** for your **Impedance**. The solver only considered the streets because of that.

> The PedestrianTime network attribute represents the time it takes a
>   pedestrian to travel on the network.

If you wanted the best route, you should set the **Impedance** to **TravelTime**. This is explained in [Exercise 3: Finding the best route using a network dataset](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Exercise_3_Finding_the_best_route_using_a_network_dataset/00470000005w000000/)

[image]

Comment: The only options available for that dataset are `PedestrianTime`, `DriveTime` and `Meters`. As the dataset for Exercise 3 already exists (the dataset for Exercise 2 had to be created by the user), would I be correct in assuming that the `TravelTime` attribute would have to be added in the network dataset wizard during creation?

Comment: Yes. You would have to create the TravelTime evaluator I guess. The same way you specified PedestrianTime and DriveTime.

Comment: Could you check if using the dataset for Exercise 3 results in the expected routes?

Comment: Exercise 3 does give the expected result. Ok, I'm going to recreate the network dataset for Exercise 2 and add that attribute, and I'll report back here what happens.

Comment: Success! Added the `TravelTime` attribute, using the same Evaluator parameters as in the Exercise 3 dataset. The route now includes the rail line (the route now takes 33 mins). Thanks!