# Adding TravelTime as Impedance in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

How do I add the TravelTime as Impedance as said at [Solving a route in a multimodal network dataset does not use all forms of transport available](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37252)?

I have tried a lot but unable to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your network need to include an attribute which contains the travel time. 
Then when you create your network dataset you can select your "cost" attributes:

[image]

In the above example my attribute is named "Minutes". This attribute indicate the travel time for each edges.

After that you should be able to select this attribute as impedance.

But of course arcmap don't know how to calculate this attribute by itself, this attribute is precomputed and estimate the travel time for each road is not an easy task.